# Prevent search text input in vuetify autocomplete from automatically checking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-1

I am using vuetify v1 and vue v2 and am currently facing an issue where when I enter a search text into the outlet autocomplete, the filtered options will automatically be checked even though I did not check them and though the v-model section.outlets array being empty. Though the options are checked, section.outlets array is still empty.

The way the code works is that if a user enters a search text, it will do wildcard matching in the database and return the matching options. If user selects "All Outlets", the other options will be disabled.

Anybody knows how to fix the issue I am currently facing?

```
<v-card-text v-for="(section, i) in form.inviteData" :key="i">
       <v-autocomplete
          label="Outlet"
          v-model="section.outlets"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          :items="outletsOption"
          :loading="outletsOptionFetching"
          :rules="requiredRules"
          :disabled="!form.client_id"
          :search-input.sync="outletNameSearchText[i]"
          @input="changeOutlets($event,i)"
          chips
          deletable-chips
          multiple
          @click="fetchDropdownDom('outlet')" 
          required
          >
          <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
             <v-checkbox 
               :label="item.name"
                v-model="section.outlets"
                class="black-label"
                :value="item.id"
                :disabled="section.outlets.length === 1 && section.outlets[0] === 'null' && item.name !== 'All Outlets'"
              >
             </v-checkbox>
           </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
.....

data() {
    return {
      outletsOption: [],
      outletsOptionFetching: false,
      outletInfiniteScroll:true,
      form:{
        client_id:'',
        inviteData:[{
        emails:'',
        outlets:'',
        role_id:'',
        }]
      },
      requiredRules: [ // allow input 0 or number
        v => ((!!v || Number.isInteger(v)) && v.toString().search(/\w/) !== -1) || 'Required'
      ],
      radioGroup: null,
      checkboxGroup: [],
      hasClient: true,
      activatedScrollDropdown:"",
      outletOffset:0,
      outletNameSearchText: [null],
      currentOutletIndex: 0,
    }
  },
watch: {
    outletNameSearchText: _debounce(async function (searchText) {
        const index = searchText.findIndex(elem => elem !== null && elem !== undefined);
        let queryString = typeof searchText[index] === 'string' && index!==-1 ? searchText[index] : null;
        if(!queryString){
            return
        }
        let hasExisted = this.outletsOption.find(({ name }) => {
          return name.toLowerCase() === queryString.toLowerCase();
        });
        if (!hasExisted) {
        await this.getOutletsOptions(queryString);
      };
    }, 1000),

  },
methods:{
async getOutletsOptions(searchText = '') {
      try {
        this.outletsOptionFetching = true;
        let offset=this.outletOffset
        let option = await this.$fetch({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'api/info_management/outlets/name_option',
          params: {
            offset,
            searchText,
            clients: JSON.stringify(
              this.form.client_id ? [this.form.client_id] : []
            ),
            ids: JSON.stringify(this.form.outlets && this.form.outlets[0] !== 'null' ? this.form.outlets : [])
          }
        }).then(({ data }) => data);
         this.outletsOption = [{ id: 'null', name: 'All Outlets' },...this.outletsOption, ...option];
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        log(error);
        this.outletsOption = [];
      } finally {
        this.outletsOptionFetching = false;
      };
    },
....

}
```

Comment: This usually happens when the key for the items (the property from `item-value`) is undefined/null. Colloquially, when nothing is selected and all items are nothing, all items are selected. Make sure the data returned by your service call fits the expected format

Comment: The data returned is in the expected format {id: XX, name: XX}. So I have no idea why its behaving this way.

Comment: Please consider to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using some code sandbox.